# Progress of playbackLikelyToKeepUp

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

When using an `AVPlayer`, is there a way to get the progress of `playbackLikelyToKeepUp`? I was thinking I could look at `loadedTimeRanges` to see how much has been buffered so far, but from what I understand, the `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` property is some internally made prediction and does not provide a value of how much data is needed for it to be true.

To put this into perspective, what I'm trying to do is to have a progress view that reaches 100% just as the video starts playing.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand how to control the internal loading of assets of the AVPlayer, but it's pretty much a black box.

Answer (score 0):

To begin playing when AVPlayer will play continuously, you can observe the Key-Value changes on the playbackLikelyToKeepUp, like this:

```
let PlayerKeepUp = "playbackLikelyToKeepUp"
var isPlayerReady:Bool = false
```

and then in your Initialiser you add:

```
// adding the Observers for Status:
self.player?.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: PlayerKeepUp, options: ([NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old]), context: &PlayerItemObserverContext)
```

And Finally, to track when the player is ready to play without getting stuck:

```
// MARK: KVO Observing Methods:
override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch (keyPath, context) {
        case (PlayerKeepUp as String, &PlayerItemObserverContext):
            if(self.player.currentItem?.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == true) {
                    self.isPlayerReady = true
// HERE YOU FILL UP YOUR PROGRESS VIEW :-)
                    self.delegate?.playerReady(self.playerURL! as String) 
            }
            break
        default:
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Last but not least, remember to Remove your KVO observance or else you'll crash when de-allocating the player:

```
deinit {
// Remove observer:              
self.player?.currentItem?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: PlayerKeepUp, context: &PlayerItemObserverContext)
}
```

Hope this helps :-)